# Return an object of objects in postgresql 15

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create an object of objects in a psql query, but I'm struggling to get the formatting right. I tried to do it with a nested jsonb_object_agg function but got this error:

```
ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested
```

The return value needs to look like this:

```
 "characteristics": {
    "Size": {
      "id": 14,
      "value": "4.0000"
    },
    "Width": {
      "id": 15,
      "value": "3.5000"
    },
    "Comfort": {
      "id": 16,
      "value": "4.0000"
    },
```

There names of the characteristics are in one table and the values in another. Here is the structure of the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS characteristics
(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
    product_id integer,
    name text
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ratingschar
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    characteristics_id integer,
    review_id integer,
    value integer
);
```

Here is my query right now, it has gone through many iterations:

```
(select jsonb_object_agg(name, jsonb_object_agg(some_value,therating)) as chars
from (select name, AVG(value) as some_value, ratingschar.id as therating from
        ratingschar
inner join characteristics
    on ratingschar.id = characteristics.id
where product_id = 465464
GROUP BY name, ratingschar.id
      ) as b
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to use jsonb_build_object instead of jsonb_object_agg. I'm not entirely sure why I can't nest agg functions like that though. Here was my final query:

```
(select jsonb_object_agg(name, json_build_object('id',the_id, 'rating',the_rating)) as chars
from (select name, AVG(value) as the_rating, ratingschar.id as the_id from
        ratingschar
inner join characteristics
    on ratingschar.id = characteristics.id
where product_id = 465464
GROUP BY name, ratingschar.id
      ) as b
     )
```